# Passing Target to Sub in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2010, I'm trying to pass 'Target' from a Worksheet_Change event to a subroutine.  The sub checks if a change has occurred within  a specific range and does certain things if it does.  The problem I'm having is that target seems to behave differently in the sub that in the calling procedure.  For instance, in the calling procedure I can use Target within an intersect, when I pass it to the sub and do the same thing I get a run time error (1004).  My code is below, I'd be grateful if someone can inform me what I'm doing wrong.

'Code on sheet - this is on several sheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        SubRout Target
End Sub
```

'Code in Module

```
Sub SubRout (ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ValidChange As Boolean

    ValidChange = True

    'Check if change on sheet was a change to cell in named range
    If Intersect(Target, Names("WB4aWBSRange").RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then ValidChange = False 

    If ValidChange = True And Target.value <> "" Then

        'Do stuff

    End If

End Sub
```

The run time error occurs on the Intersect line, but if I move all the code up to the calling routine it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The error is not because of that. Error is because of `Names("WB4aWBSRange").RefersToRange`. You can't use it like that.

Use this

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("WB4aWBSRange")) Is Nothing Then ValidChange = False
```

Comment: Thank you.  That has fixed it, but for my knowledge how are the two treated differently, and why does my version work when that code is moved up to the Worksheet_Change event?

Comment: I think I might have figured it out.  The 'WB4aWBSRange' is a named range at the sheet level rather than the workbook level - so perhaps when you move out to the code in the module it can't reconcile it back to a single named range.  Correct? Or a mile off!?

Comment: @laserdunc - `Names` is a property of the worksheet.  When you call it from the worksheet module, it uses it in worksheet scope.  When you call if from a non-worksheet module, it uses `Names` in the global scope.

Comment: @laserdunc: Yup :-) By the way do you know that for multiple sheets you can use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` in lieu of `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. You have to then place the code in thisworkbook and you can get away by create a sub in a module ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because `is Nothing` returns a Boolean value the first if statement isn't needed:

`ValidChange = Not Intersect(Target, Range("WB4aWBSRange")) Is Nothing`

I would rather not use the variable at all and do this instead:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("WB4aWBSRange")) Is Nothing' then


    If Target.value <> "" Then


        'Do stuff

    End If

End Sub
```